# How do I get the Code Review Id in a custom section of the code review page?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a visual studio extension that has a section on the code review page. I would like access to the information about the rest of the code review page, specifically what code review is current on the page being displayed. I should be able to access the workitemId but so far I have not figured out how.

**Edit**
Using Cole's suggestion I have accessed the PageContent but I do not know what type I should cast the content to. Nor do I know when it will be available. I would like access both when I initialize my section, and later. Here is my code when I try to initialize the section:

```
 public override object SectionContent
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.SectionContent == null)
            {
                var teamExplorerPage = this.GetService<ITeamExplorerPage>();
                var pageContent = teamExplorerPage.PageContent;
                this.model.CodeReviewId = pageContent;
                base.SectionContent = new CodePlusTeamExplorerSectionView(this.ServiceProvider, this.model);
            }

            return base.SectionContent;
        }
    }
```

When I debug the code I see that a DataContext is available on the PageContent, but I do not know what type to cast the pageContent (orITeamExplorerPage) to, to gain access to it. Also the DataContext has a CodeReviewId property which seems like the value I need but it is null at this point of the Lifecycle. If I want to retrieve some additional data based on the CodeReviewId when/where is it available?

Comment: could you please provide related screen shot about Code Review Id, in addition, please check if it could retrieve related content by using ITeamExplorerPage.PageContent  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.controls.iteamexplorerpage.pagecontent(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still trying to figure out how to get it earlier in the lifecycle of the page but from an event like a button click in the page I can retrieve the value using reflection. This seems like a bit of a hack, perhaps someone else has a better way, but here it is.

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var teamExplorer = this.GetService<ITeamExplorer>();
        var currentPage = teamExplorer.CurrentPage;
        var currentContent = currentPage.PageContent;

        Type type = currentContent.GetType();
        PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty("DataContext");
        var dataContext = pi.GetValue(currentContent);

        Type contextTypetype = dataContext.GetType();
        PropertyInfo contextTypePi = contextTypetype.GetProperty("CodeReviewId");
        var codeReviewId = contextTypePi.GetValue(dataContext);

        var context = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        context.Add("WorkItemId", codeReviewId);

        teamExplorer.NavigateToPage(new Guid(TeamExplorerPageIds.ViewCodeReview), context);
    }
```